# Will the passengers aboard Spaceship Neptune get rewarded?

Tags: astronauts, tourism

The tourists who flew on New Shepard from Blue Origin got their astronaut wings once they returned. Spaceship Neptune will not pass the Karman line unlike New Shepard did, however it will pass the Armstrong line. Will the tourists onboard get any rewards for flying with it?

Comment: Given the answer here https://space.stackexchange.com/a/54269/26356 neither Blue Origin nor Neptune can hand out FAA Astronaut wings, making this a question of what a business is including in the package souvenir wise.

Comment: @GremlinWranger even if they cannot get their astronaut wings are there any other rewards they can get?

Comment: The only people who can answer what kinds of trophies Space Perspective are going to hand out, are Space Perspective. Why don't you ask them instead of random strangers on the interwebs?

Comment: @TheRocketfan since the precedent is set, I'd fully expect them to be handing out a badge of some sort, if only so they can try to convince people who have flown on Virgin or Blue Origin to collect the full set. There may be high altitude balloon groups that recongise flights like this but would expect them to only award something to the 'pilot' or possibly the design team.

Comment: If passing the Armstrong line is enough to get rewarded, all tourists having flown in concorde deserve this medal.